# Rename a file after building it in Sublime Text 3

Tags: filenames, rename, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is it possible to rename a file after building it in Sublime Text 3? By default, the output is the same as the input; so filename.scss is built to filename.css. But what if I want filename.scss.css by default (to indicate that this file is based off of a scss file). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Read through the [Build Systems Reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) for details. First, there are several variables you can use. `$file` is the reference to the full path of the current file, say `/home/foo/test.php`. There is also `$filepath` (`/home/foo`), `$file_name` (`test.php`), `$file_extension` (`php`), `$file_base_name` (`test`), and [some others](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#build-system-variables). You can also use regexes just about anywhere inside curly braces (`$file` is the same as `${file}`). For example, `${file/\.php/\.txt/}` will rename its suffix from `.php` to `.txt` (`/home/foo/test.txt`). `${filepath/testing/production}` changes the directory. Here are several combined in a contrived example:

```js
"cmd": ["myprocessor", "--infile", "$file", "--outfile", "/mnt/${project_name}/var/www/assets/${file_base_name/test/final}.css"],
...
```

For your particular case, this should work:

```js
"cmd": ["myprocessor", "--infile", "$file", "--outfile", "$filepath/$file_name.css"],
```

should take `/path/to/yourfile.scss` and spit out the processed `/path/to/yourfile.scss.css` if that's what you want.